# circular import error in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two custom modules in the root project folder:

```
root/setting.py
root/utils/custom_exception.py
root/custom_authentication.py
```

I am importing from rest_framework import exception_handler,
`from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException` in the `custom_exception.py` module. When I import `CustomExceptionClass` from `custom_exception.py` in `custom_authentication.py`, I get a cyclical import error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'exception_handler' from partially initialized module 'rest_framework.views' (most likely due to a circular import)`

However when I import the same exception class inside the authenticate method , the error is gone. Does anyone know why I am not able to import globally?

Comment: Because if you move it *in* the authenticate method, it will import when *running* the method. Whereas if you write it at the top of the file, it will import from the moment it interprets (and thus imports) that file...

Comment: @markwalker_ I would like to import it globally, do you know how to do it?